# Principle coordinates analysis - visualization and assigning text to graph in r

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, multidimensional-scaling

I've recently run a principle coordinates analysis in r with ~ 200 subjects and 17 binary variables. I've plotted my points successfully, the challenge I'm facing is that when I plot the text with the points on the graph (example attached) I'm unable to differentiate the text. Can anyone recommend away where I can display this information in a visually pleasing way? If not is there a matrix i can display?

Thanks!

My code below:

```
> data.dst <- dist(Data, method = "binary")
> cmd <- cmdscale(data.dst, k=3)
> plot(cmd)
> text(cmd, Names, pos=3)
>
```

Plot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKcVA.jpg